# Calling an Oracle function from SQL Server Linked Server

Tags: sql-server, oracle, linked-server

I have setup a linked server pointing to an Oracle DB. I want to call a function ABC in a package XYZ passing parameter K. What will be the syntax to do this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I used the following syntax and it worked for me.

```
EXECUTE (Query, Parameters) AT LinkedServerName
```

Example:

```
EXECUTE ( 'BEGIN ? := Package.MyFunction(?,?); END;', @ReturnValue, @InputPara, @OutputPara OUTPUT ) AT LinkedServerName
```

Important Points:

- Don't forget the BEGIN and END syntax when calling functions
- Don't forget the semicolon at the end "END**;**"
- For using the above syntax you need to enable RPC for the linked server
- Oracle will not consider the call as a function call unless you accept the output in a variable