# Call Oracle function with ref cursor output in SQL Server linked server?

Tags: sql-server, oracle, linked-server

How do I need to call an Oracle function with ref cursor output in a SQL Server linked server?

I used this statement:

```
SELECT *
FROM OPENQUERY(oracle, 'select * from functionname(''N'',''2016-11-01'')')
```

but I get this error

> OLE DB provider "OraOLEDB.Oracle" for linked server "oracle" returned message "ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended".
>
> Msg 7321, Level 16, State 2, Line 33
>   An error occurred while preparing the query "select * from functionname('N','2016-11-01')" for execution against OLE DB provider "OraOLEDB.Oracle" for linked server "oracle".

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help? 
[Calling an Oracle function from SQL Server Linked Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1270113/calling-an-oracle-function-from-sql-server-linked-server)

```
EXECUTE (Query, Parameters) AT LinkedServerName
```

Comment: I tryed it but my output is ref cursor and mssql don't have this type