# How to call oracle function with no parameter from SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, oracle, t-sql

I need to call an Oracle function Function `PK_DM_API_EDIT_ENTITY.DONE` from SQL Server.

I call it like this in Oracle:

```
begin
    PK_DM_API_EDIT_ENTITY.CHANGE ('dep', '322'); 
    PK_DM_API_EDIT_ENTITY.SET_VALUE ('id_sub', '102'); 
    PK_DM_API_EDIT_ENTITY.DONE;
end
```

It works fine in Oracle - string was updated.

But if I call this function from SQL Server:

```
EXECUTE ( 'begin PK_DM_API_EDIT_ENTITY.CHANGE ( ?,? ); end; ', 'dep', '322') AT [MSD]
EXECUTE ( 'begin PK_DM_API_EDIT_ENTITY.SET_VALUE ( ?,? ); end; ', 'id_sub', '102') AT [MSD]
EXECUTE ( 'begin ? := PK_MDM_API_EDIT_ENTITY.done; end;') AT [MSD]
```

Then the string is not updated. I don't know why... can you please help?

Comment: [Calling an Oracle function from SQL Server Linked Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1270113/calling-an-oracle-function-from-sql-server-linked-server)

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure your code is a function?

> I call it like this in Oracle:
>
> ```sql
> begin
>    PK_DM_API_EDIT_ENTITY.CHANGE ('dep', '322'); 
>    PK_DM_API_EDIT_ENTITY.SET_VALUE ('id_sub', '102'); 
>    PK_DM_API_EDIT_ENTITY.DONE;
> end
> ```
>
> It works fine in Oracle - string was updated.

That would not work if `PK_DM_API_EDIT_ENTITY.DONE` is a function as you do not assign the return value to a variable. However, it would work if `PK_DM_API_EDIT_ENTITY.DONE` is a procedure.

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/Vu-UCabo)

---

If it is a `PROCEDURE` (and not a `FUNCTION`) and you want to execute it from SQL Server then just use exactly the same code that worked in Oracle.

```sql
EXECUTE ( 'begin PK_DM_API_EDIT_ENTITY.CHANGE ( ?,? ); PK_DM_API_EDIT_ENTITY.SET_VALUE ( ?,? ); PK_MDM_API_EDIT_ENTITY.done; end; ', 'dep', '322', 'id_sub', '102') AT [MSD]
```

or:

```sql
EXECUTE ( 'begin PK_DM_API_EDIT_ENTITY.CHANGE ( ?,? ); end; ', 'dep', '322') AT [MSD]
EXECUTE ( 'begin PK_DM_API_EDIT_ENTITY.SET_VALUE ( ?,? ); end; ', 'id_sub', '102') AT [MSD]
EXECUTE ( 'begin  PK_MDM_API_EDIT_ENTITY.done; end;') AT [MSD]
```

Comment: PK_DM_API_EDIT_ENTITY   - it is a package

Comment: @Kirik `PK_DM_API_EDIT_ENTITY` is a package but what is `PK_DM_API_EDIT_ENTITY.DONE`? You state in the question that it is a function but the way you state "works" you are using it as if it is a procedure (and your code would have invalid syntax if it was a function) which is why I am questioning whether your description of it is correct.